# How can I clear screen in python cmd?

Tags: python, screen, python-cmd

How can I clear the screen from former results in python cmd?
I want to clear the screen in each level of a loop, I mean how to clear the results and print the new one instead of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ?

```
 >>> import os
 >>> clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
 >>> clear()
```

Comment: What on earth is ``cls``? ``^L`` ftw

Comment: This is clear console command in Windows. Function system() directly executes shell commands https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: **CL**ear **S**creen

Comment: If you use unix, use `clear` instead of `cls`